# Boolean is not iterable but method also returns a list, TyperError is raised

Tags: python, python-2.7

do_tables_exist() will return False if no tables need to be created and a list of strings if there is a table that needs to be created; the method can return either a boolean value or a list but never both. Here's the method:

```
def create_tables(self):
    """ Creates tables for RSS news feeds

    Creates db tables where each RSS link feeds
    into a separate table because it's easier
    to aggregate then deaggregate.
    """
    if self.do_tables_exist() != False:
        # Open database locally
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.path + "FeedMe.db")
        conn.isolation_level = None
        c = conn.cursor()
        transaction_query = "BEGIN; "
        for table_name in self.do_tables_exist():
            table = "CREATE TABLE " +  table_name + \
                    "( primary_key text, title text," + \
                    " description text, link text, published text); "
            transaction_query = transaction_query + table
            # Which tables are being entered?
            print "\t" + table_name

        transaction_query = transaction_query + " COMMIT;" 
        # Create table in sqlite3
        c.executescript(transaction_query)
        # close sqlite3 db
        conn.close()

    elif self.do_tables_exist() == False:
        print("\n\tNo new tables need to be created")

    else:
        raise UserWarning("do_tables_exist() not returning a value")
```

On the following line I receive a "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable".

```
for table_name in self.do_tables_exist():
```

This confuses me because my intention to only iterate over the object when do_tables_exist() returned a list.

Do you know why I am receiving this error? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Without seeing your `do_tables_exist` call I cannot be sure, but the approach I would take is to call the function something like `get_tables_to_create` and return the empty list when nothing needs to be created. That avoids the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
tables = self.do_tables_exist()
if tables:
    for table_name in tables:
        #do stuff
```